# Declaring and Defining Global Variables as Function Result Sometimes Works?

Tags: javascript

Some programming languages I've worked with are fussy about setting global variables to the result of a function, so I'm in the habit of doing it in a main() or an init().

This was sent to me by a friend and much to my surprise, it works totally fine locally on my computer and on hers, but won't work on either of our servers:

```
function getValue(val) {
    return document.getElementById(val);
}
var myValue = getValue("output"); // is this kosher?
function init() {
    myValue.innerHTML = "foo"; //error: myValue is null
    //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="bar"; //this works though
}
window.onload = init
```

However, oddly enough, this works on the servers as well as locally:

```
function getValue(val) {
    return val;
}
var myValue = getValue("output");
function init() {
    alert(myValue);
}
window.onload = init;
```

I fixed it by doing this:

```
function getValue(val) {
    return document.getElementById(val);
}
var myValue; // don't set the value here
function init() {
    myValue = getValue("output"); // but here instead
    myValue.innerHTML = "foo"; // this is fine
}
window.onload = init
```

...but now I'm confused as to why the 2nd block of code would work if the 1st one doesn't.  Is it something to do with the JS running through the declarations before the HTML document has time to load when on a server?

Just for reference, the document is as such:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <script src="test.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="output">
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first block you're trying to get an element *before* the dom(the html itself) fully rendering and initialization. That is why the third block works, because you get it on `window.load`, the event which runs *after*  the html initialization.

The second block works because it is just a string, so its ok.

Here your "output" element doesn't exists yet. So `myValue` will be set to `null`:

```
var myValue = getValue("output");
```

That is why it is `null` inside the `window.load`.

Comment: Any reason why it works on my computer and not on my server though?

Comment: Your code should not be anything related to the server since it runs in your browser. It is too vague to say that *"It doesn't works in my server"*. Did you double checked the code? Did you tried Ctrl+F5 in case of any old code being cached? Check your console tab in dev tools(F12) for error or put a [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement in the server code and debug it.

Comment: what would you say about this  https://jsfiddle.net/94h77ya2/ 
Similar issue like OP works on fiddle but not on my local file.
This is OP first code which was working on computer but not on server

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown i agree and stand by your answer but i'm bit confused after executing code

Comment: @CY5 idk how you created your *local file* - perhaps you can dump it raw on a pastebin and show us - but, in case of the fiddle it doesn't works because you're not calling the `init()` function. You've set it in the `window.onload` but if you check the initialization config(the dropdown under the library dropdown on the left upper corner), it is set to run on `load` event. So it is already being run in the load event, the init won't be called again. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/94h77ya2/1/

Comment: ok i created the same example of my local in JSBIN https://jsbin.com/jedivapoqi/edit?html,js,output  and its similar to OP first code and i get foo printed

Comment: @CY5 it works as it supose to. Please inspect your div "foo" text and you will figure a `script` tag under it. It is your code. In it, its declares the `load` event. In that moment, the load event doens't run yet. So your new bound function will be called on the event and the element `output` will the there.

Comment: @CY5 idk how to explain you better. I'm afraid I have to draw it for you. Try reading my answer, as well Sterling's answer again.

Comment: thanks, as i said you before i stand to your point but the online compiler trick me  i thought the code inside JSbin is running the same way like  my local file runing in  browser (i.e JS will be in head tag)   but i was wrong they have appended JS inside body(in JSBIN) which is good practice and which you pointed out

Comment: @CY5 these fiddlers are pretty tricky regarding script's location. I've seem a lot of users with problem with that, actually. When I first met, until I get used to them, I do made mistakes too.

Answer (score 1):

In the first block of code, the code is run to grab the doc element immediately. So the element doesn't exist yet. Since you grab the element in the init method on the second block, which runs when the DOM is ready, this element now exists.

If you load the JS script AFTER your HTML (aka, at the very bottom of your  tag), your first block would run because the DOM elements exist before the script is run.

Comment: Any reason why it works on my computer and not on my server though?